# Angular Cant call function inside of FB.api()

Tags: angular, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have a problem with `Facebook API` in `Angular 6`: I can not execute or change the value of a variable inside the function FB.api

What I try is to overwrite the fields of the form with the data obtained from facebook, but when I want to patch the values I get `Cannot read property 'patchValue' of undefined`

This is my button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" (click)="submitLogin();">Login with facebook</button>
```

The component.ts

```
/* ... angular imports ... */

declare const FB: any;

export class CouponsComponent implements OnInit {

  forma: FormGroup;
  showForm: boolean = false;
  usuario: any;

  /* more code ... */

  ngOnInit() {

    (window as any).fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
                appId      : {api-key},
                cookie     : true,
                xfbml      : true,
                version    : 'v3.2'
            });
            FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  }

  submitLogin(){

    FB.login((response)=> {

      if (response.status === 'connected') {        

                FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name, name, email'}, function(response) {

                    if (response) {
                        this.usuario = response;

                    this.forma.patchValue({ // -> get Cannot read property 'patchValue' of undefined
                        nombre: this.usuario.name + ' ' + this.usuario.last_name,
                        email: this.usuario.email,
                    })

                        console.log(this.usuario); // -> get fine response
                        console.log(this.forma); // -> get undefined
                    }

                });

                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log(this.usuario); // -> get undefined
                }, 3000)

            } else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
      });
  }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is not a component reference anymore in `api` scope. Best way to get component reference is to at the start at the `submitLogin` declare `cost self = this;` and later instead of `this.forma.patchValue` call `self.forma.patchValue`.

You can also instead of `function(response)` make `(response)=>` this way it will not create a new scope and `this` will be a component.